# How do I overlay text on an image who's size is to be set?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am trying to make a bar chart using tables, which I have almost accomplished to my liking. The last step I want is text over my image which represents the bar. Here is the code I have thus far for building my little bar charts:

```
$height = 50;

//build length
$width = 450;
$multi = $brewAvg / 5;
$width = $width * $multi;
print " <tr > <td > $count.  <a href=\"$breweryURL\"> $brewR</a>  </td>   <td > <img src=\"blueBar.png\"  width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\">  </td>  </tr> ";
```

And this produces something like this:

[image]

You can see in the code how I simply calculate the length of the bar based on a breweries rating. What I want to do next is have the rating number show on top of each breweries on the left hand side. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Update:

I tried a tutorial I read here:

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/css-text-over-image.html

and I changed my code to this:

```
print "<div class=\"overlay\"> ";
            print " <tr valign=\"middle\" > <td > $count.  <a href=\"$breweryURL\"> $brewR</a>  </td>   <td > <img src=\"blueBar.png\"  width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\">  </td>  </tr> ";
            print" 
                <div class=\"text\">
                <p> $brewAvg  </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            ";
```

And my css I added was this:

```
<style>
.overlay {
    position:relative;
    float:left; /* optional */
}
.overlay .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; /* in conjunction with left property, decides the text position */
    left:10px;
    width:300px; /* optional, though better have one */
}


</style>
```

And it did put any of the value son top of my images. All the text is in a list above all the bars like this:

[image]

After using the help in the response I marked the answer, here is the result:

[image]

Now I just need to figure out how to vertically center everything so the grey background looks nicer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your print code with this one :

```
print " <tr > <td > $count.  <a href=\"$breweryURL\"> $brewR</a>  </td>   <td style=\"position: relative;\"> <img style=\"z-index: 8;\" src=\"blueBar.png\"  width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"> <span style=\"position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; color:#fff; z-index: 9; font-size: 14px;\">$brewAvg</span> </td>  </tr> ";
```

Of course I have hard-coded you can move appropriate style to your CSS file, and with changing top, left you can re-position the **span** for rating number.

Comment: Wrong HTML usage I have corrected your setup. Actually my response has better CSS just hard-coded. Don't forget about **z-index**

`print " <tr valign=\"middle\" > <td > $count.  <a href=\"$breweryURL\"> $brewR</a>  </td>   <td class=\"overlay\" > <img src=\"blueBar.png\"  width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"> <div class=\"text\"><p> $brewAvg  </p> </div>  </td>  </tr> ";`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I just changed top to 4px and it was perfect!

Comment: Just noticed this does not work in firefox. All the numbers that are supposed to be on the blue bars are all ontop of each other in the top left of the page

Comment: Hi, please provide an URL so I'll post a fix.

Comment: Here is quick fix due to CSS 2.1 TD position: relative is undefined , you should put your element in a div wrapper. Just tested on firefox it is working fine.

wrapper : `<div style="position: relative;"></div>`

your code : `<td><div style="position: relative;"><img width="384.003" height="25" src="blueBar.png" 8;"="" "z-index:="" style="padding-top:5px;"> <span style="position: absolute; top: 7px; left: 10px; color:#fff; z-index: 9; font-size: 14px;">4.2667</span></div></td>`

Comment: I think I am putting it in the wrong place?

http://www.beerportfolio.com/v2/discover.php

Comment: Actually it looks like failing on even numbers, on odd numbers it works fine. If you provide php loop code, I can make correction for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any sort of black magic to achieve this .. just put the brewery name and rating in the same `td`, perhaps separated by a div.  The number can also be in a `td` so it can be vertically aligned.  Something like:

```
<td>1.</td>
<td>Rating<br><a>Company</a></td>
<td><img></td>
```